# Submit form without bean validation

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, bean-validation

I've got a form which has a domain model with some `JSR-303` validation beans. Now I would like to include a "Save draft" feature without any validation. If I set `immediate=true` on my corresponding commandButton validation is skipped but also the form submit.

Is there a way to update the model in my save draft action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<f:validateBean>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateBean.html) where on you set the `disabled` attribute.

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}">
    <f:validateBean disabled="#{bean.draft}" />
</h:inputText>
```

If this evaluates `true`, this will skip all bean validation on the property associated with the input's value. You should only ensure that the `boolean draft` property is set before the validations phase takes place. E.g.

```html
<h:commandButton value="Save draft" action="#{bean.saveDraft}">
    <f:param name="draft" value="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.draft}")
private boolean draft;
```

or if it's a view scoped bean on which `@ManagedProperty` won't work:

```
public boolean isDraft() {
    return "true".equals(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("draft"));
}
```

Another way is to check in EL if the button is pressed by determining the presence of its parameter name. For example, with the following form and button ID

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input}">
        <f:validateBean disabled="#{not empty param['form:draft']}" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="draft" value="Save draft" action="#{bean.saveDraft}" />
</h:form>
```