# How to skip Bean Validation on inputs when pressing specific button

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, commandbutton

I add/delete rows dynamically using a datatable. I have a problem with deleting rows. In fact, I want to delete a row without validating the fields. At the same time, I need my model updated, so using `immediate="true"` is inadequate (http://blog.jerryorr.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html).
This is my code:

```
<h:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{bean.list}" var="l" style="width: 100%;">
    <h:column>
        <h:panelGrid styleClass="dr-pnl" style="width: 100%;">
            <h:outputLabel for="name">Name</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{l.name}"></h:inputText>
             <h:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete">
                <f:ajax listener="#{bean.delete(l)}" execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:commandButton id="add" value="Add">
            <f:ajax listener="#{bean.add}" execute="@form" render="tbl" immediate="true" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
</h:dataTable>
```

To get around this problem, I thought that I should use Javascript to delete the content of my fields before calling the method `bean.delete(l)`. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which valdiation are you talking about? BV? There are no validators in the code.

Comment: I have a Regex (only letters) validation on the field name in my model.

Comment: So, BV (Bean Validation) as in `@javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Comment: Is this then acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436016/submit-form-without-bean-validation/

Comment: I tried it and I got this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: param.draft`